# Not being able to access UITableView (of second view controller) from Container View of First View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on one iOS objective C project where I want to use navigation drawer in my app. I don't want to use any third party library. I am developing all code by own.

These are some of the screen shots of my First or HomeViewController that I have done already.

[image]
[image]

When I click to menu button, My drawer (Container View that embeds Second or NavigationTableViewController) opens successfully. But I am not being able to scroll or access the table elements from Home View Controller.

Please help.

I am also posting my code here.

**HomeViewController.m**

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "HomeCollectionViewItemCell.h"
#import "NavigationTableViewController.h"

#define kCellsPerRow    2

@interface HomeViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewNavigationPopUp;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewFlowLayout;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewSlider;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControlSlider;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger sliderImageCount;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

#pragma mark - View controller life cycle methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setSliderImageCount:0];

    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [self.imageViewSlider setAnimationImages:@[[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_img1.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_img2.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_img3.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_img4.jpg"]]];

    //[self.imageViewSlider setImage:[self.imageViewSlider.animationImages objectAtIndex:self.sliderImageCount]];
    [self.pageControlSlider setCurrentPage:self.sliderImageCount];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageSliderSwipe:)];
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.imageViewSlider addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageSliderSwipe:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.imageViewSlider addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGFloat length = (self.collectionView.frame.size.width - self.collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset.left - self.collectionViewFlowLayout.sectionInset.right - (self.collectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * (kCellsPerRow - 1))) / kCellsPerRow;
    [self.collectionViewFlowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(length, length)];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

#pragma mark - Collection view methods

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HomeCollectionViewItemCell *homeCollectionViewItemCell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HomeCollectionViewItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return homeCollectionViewItemCell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 4;
}

#pragma mark - button acrion methods

- (IBAction)buttonToggleDrawerMenuAction:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];

    CGRect newViewFrame = [self.view frame];
    newViewFrame.origin.x = [self.view frame].origin.x > 0.0 ? 0.0 : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width * 0.797;
    [self.view setFrame:newViewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)handleImageSliderSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
    [self setSliderImageCount:[swipe direction] == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft ? (self.sliderImageCount + 1) : (self.sliderImageCount - 1)];
    [self setSliderImageCount:(self.sliderImageCount < 0) ? 3 : self.sliderImageCount];
    [self setSliderImageCount:(self.sliderImageCount > 3) ? 0 : self.sliderImageCount];
    [self.imageViewSlider setImage:[self.imageViewSlider.animationImages objectAtIndex:self.sliderImageCount]];
    [self.pageControlSlider setCurrentPage:self.sliderImageCount];
}

#pragma mark - other

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"EmbedSegue"]) {
        NavigationTableViewController *navigationTableViewController = (NavigationTableViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [navigationTableViewController setHomeViewController:self];
    }
}

@end
```

**NavigationTableViewController.m**

```
#import "NavigationTableViewController.h"

@interface NavigationTableViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *navigationTableView;

@end

@implementation NavigationTableViewController

#pragma mark - View controller life cycle methods

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationTableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.navigationTableView setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

#pragma mark - table view methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NavigationTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item - %ld", (long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - other

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

@end
```

**NavigationTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class HomeViewController;
@interface NavigationTableViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) HomeViewController *homeViewController;

@end
```

**Update:**

I got some clue but not getting why this happens? Actually my code is correct but due to auto layout constraints I came across this problem.

Lets say frame of my view controller's view is (0,0,414,736) and container frame is (-330,0,330,736). 
My auto layout have following constraints:

- 1. container Height = [viewController view].size.height
  2. container Width = [viewController view].size.width * 0.8 // 0 is constant and multiplier is 0.8
  3. container Trailing = [viewController view] leading + 0; // 0 is constant and multiplier is 1
  4. container Top = [viewController view] Top layout Guide i.e. 0

At this point I can scroll as well as select the Items in table view. But  when I press menu button, my containers frame changes and It becomes (0,0,330,736). Now as my container frame change occurs I cant scroll or select items inside tableview.

**Basically what I mean is that If you are going to change frame of container during runtime, It will not allow to access any view components that embed into it.**

If anybody known what is the remedy for this issue then please let me know. **Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel for Slide menu? There is very Robust third party unit for this, [SERevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) which is used by thousands of apps world wide. Is there anything specific due to which you need your custom Side menu?

Comment: And why are you changing frames yourself? Use autolayout to fix the frames for different screen sizes. You are putting a lot of work on yourself when you should have been focusing only on functionality.

Comment: actually I dont wanna use third party libraries. And I am also using autolayout to fix frames for different layouts. I just wrote in update for understanding of readers. As you said I am not changing frame of container, It automatically changing due to autolayout. Frame of container also chaging when my view controllers view changing its position. This heppens because --> container Trailing = [viewController view] leading + 0

Comment: Reason behind not using third party is that I cant do customizations in future also some libraries contains deprecated methods